# Converting a bunch of System.out.prints in one JOptionPane message box

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, system.out

I am trying to convert the output of this code into one JOptionPane message box. The code generates a 20x20 box of used to contain a "turtle" that a user can move around within the box that works along with an array to keep the turtle within the box boundaries. The "*" is left behind by the turtle when the user tells it to draw a path.

```
public void display() {
    for (int i = 0; i < colSize+2; i++)
        System.out.print("–");
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++) {
        System.out.print("|");
        for (int j = 0; j < colSize; j++) {
            if (i == currentRow && j == currentCol)
                System.out.print("T");
            else if (floor[i][j] == 0)
                System.out.print(" ");
            else System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println ("|");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < colSize+2; i++)
        System.out.print("–");
    System.out.println();
}
```

I've looked at a few threads on Stack Overflow about using StringBuilder with JOptionPane, but I can't figure out how to use multiple StringBuilders to work in one single JOptionPane message box. If anybody can help, it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use just ***one*** StringBuilder, not multiple. Where you see `System.out.println(...)` instead `append(...)` to your StringBuilder.

Comment: Wow I'm dumb, didn't realize append "stacks". Thanks a lot! This actually answers my question, I got it working properly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state:

> but I can't figure out how to use multiple StringBuilders to work in one single JOptionPane message box.

Use just ***one*** StringBuilder, not multiple.  Where you see `System.out.println(...)` instead `append(...)` to your StringBuilder. For example,

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < something.length; i++) {
  sb.append(/* something */ + "\n");
}
// ... etc...

JOptionPane.showMessage(null, sb.toString());
```